# Microsoft Graph SDK for PHP - 400 bad request - trying to get data

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I have an Excel file added to the drive. I want to get data from it so in the first place I added permission (Files.ReadWrite) according to the documentation to my application on the azure portal.

First, I get an access token from this url:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

I receive a token, which I then use to complete the GET request from the url:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{drive-item-id}/workbook/worksheets/XX/range(address='A4:C4)`

I set headers a token according to the documentation of course

```
'headers' => [
     'Accept' => 'application/json',
     'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->token
]
```

And in response I get:

> Message: Client error: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me...
>   resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: {"error": {"code":
>   "BadRequest", "message": "Current authenticated context is not valid
>   for this request. (truncated ...) "

How should I do authorize/get token that it to work?

Best regards

Comment: There isn't a lot of detail here. Please explain how you are obtaining your token.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur 
I did a request to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token"
providing client_id, scope, redirect_uri, client_secret and grant_type. From this I get object where I have access_token or my token, which I still use in the next request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `/me` with Client Credentials (i.e Application scopes) because there is no "me". You need to specify `/users/{userId | userPrincipalName}`.

Comment: Thanks. How to get userId or userPrincipalName?

Comment: You can retrieve it from `/users`

Comment: I have added permissions to the application, I changed my login endpoint instead of "common" I have a lease ID but now gets "Authorization_RequestDenied". What am I missing? Any subscription?

Comment: You can't use `/common` with Client Credentials. You need to provide the tenant id so it knows which tenant you're authenticating too (`Common` relies on the user's email address to determine this).

Comment: Yes I wrote that I used provide tenant id but I have "Authorization_RequestDenied" for now. What should I do it now? I set permissions to the application. Should I have any subscription?

Comment: Thank you very much your help. It is working now. I have mistake with "Tenant does not have a SPO license" for now :P 
Best regards.